# Python: mask/remove the least significant 2 bits of every 16-bit integer

Tags: python, arrays, list, bit-manipulation, bitarray

I want to remove the least significant 2 bits of every 16-bit integer from a bitarray. They're stored like this:

```
010101**00**10010101101100**00**10101010.....
```

(The zeroes between the asterisks will be removed. There are two of them every 16 bits (ignoring the very first)).

I can simply eliminate them with a regular for loop checking indexes (the 7th and 8th after every 16 bits).

But... is there another more *pythonic* way to do this? I'm thinking about some slice notation or maybe comprehension lists. Perhaps I could divide every number by 4 and encode every one with 14 bits (if there's a way to do that).

Comment: Editing  the title to better reflect question, the question is really not about general bit *array* manipulation, but much simpler

Answer (score 2):

You can clear bits quite easily with masking. If you want to clear bits 8 and 7 you can do it like this:

```
a = int('10010101101100',2)
mask = ~((1 << 7) | (1 << 8))
bin(a&mask)
```

more information about masking from [here!](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation)